# Linking R codes to azure

Tags: r, azure, azure-web-app-service

I developed an algorithm using R 5.2 and now I need to import this into the azure platform. I'm confused with the way to link the code file to azure. I'm using the following packages and has formed a function called 'clustering'. I plan to link this function with azure and all I have to do is import the relevant variables to the function to get the output. I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

```
library(timeSeries)
library(TSdist)
library(tseries)
library(lubridate)
library(TSclust)
library(bizdays)
library(dtwclust)
library(cluster)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(ggthemes)
library(base)
library(factoextra)
library(NbClust)
library(TSdist)
library(dbscan)
library(data.tree)

    clustering = function(codes1, m)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not really a specific coding question but more of a coding *project*, as supported by the 300+ lines of code (requiring 18 additional libraries) that you've included. You're much more likely to get positive feedback if you rephrase your question to something more "answerable". Provide a minimal code example and show what didn't work (or where you hit a snag) when running it through Azure.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thank you for your feedback and I made changes in the question I hope now it's more understandable